# Desired state configuration

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, dsc

I have two web servers and one service server and a database server and all these servers are domain joined. And I have set my private build agent from VSTS from where I can build my artifacts and based on build configuration. And all my DEV,QA and STAGING environments are setup on those servers.

My problem is i am looking for a way using PowerShell Desired state configuration such a way that based on the environment artifacts (DEV,QA and STAGING) the scripts has to copy the artifacts to specific location on those "TWO web-servers" and ensure the website is configured correctly with all the required permissions where these artifacts are used to host IIS website and perform the delete and creation action of particular windows service on "SERVICE service" and should also perform the  migration activities on "DATABASE server" for particular database. since I have separated database for each individual environment.

Any kind of help or suggestion would be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Does the environments DEV,QA and STAGING need to be deployed by different artifacts? If so, what if you use three release definitions separately? And can you share the release definition(s) you are using now?

Comment: yes , but the problem is i don't want use VSTS for deployments i want deployments to be done by power shell scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestions are:

- Don't use DSC for deployment (i.e. deploy applications or databases)
- Use DSC for configuration (e.g. install IIS)
- Install the VSTS Agent on each server in Deployment Groups mode, running  as a service with local administrator privileges
- Use the IIS Deploy Tasks designed for Deployment Groups
- Use the Powershell Task to manage the Windows Services (tip. `help *-Service`)

Comment: Thank you Giulio for the suggestion , but my requirements is in such way that i should not be using VSTS for the deployments. Instead it has to be done through power shell scripts. That is why i am going for DSC configurations. where i can be able to configure the servers and deploy my stuff from script.

Comment: My first two points still applies: use DSC to configure a server, use simple Powershell to deploy apps. Main justification is different frequency of change, different security another (DSC grants the deploying user specific permissions)

Comment: Thank you Giulio . I will consider that